# Unexpected behaviour of implementing depth-first search pseudocode

Tags: java, graph, depth-first-search

I tried to implement depth-first search iterative using this pseudocode:

```
iterative DFS(Vertex v)
    mark v visited
    make an empty Stack S
    push all vertices adjacent to v onto S
    while S is not empty do
        Vertex w is pop off S
        for all Vertex u adjacent to w do
            if u is not visited then
                mark u visited
                push u onto S
```

which I found on this link: http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs2321/www/newLectures/26_Depth_First_Search.html

But, when I implemented it, and tested it on multiple test-examples it does not produce the expected result, i.e. the vertices are not printed in the expected order. Here is my code:

```
public void dfs(int start) {
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
        boolean[] visited = new boolean[E.length];
        stack.push(start);
        while(!stack.empty()) {
            Integer vertex = stack.pop();
            System.out.print(vertex + " ");
            for(Edge e: E[vertex]) {
                if(!visited[e.v]) {
                    stack.push(e.v);
                    visited[e.v] = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am asking if someone could help me with the implementation of the pseudocode, and help me understand my error.

Comment: Can you give us example of simple graph for which the output is incorrect?

Comment: Yes, one example is this input: vertices 7,
edges 9, and pairs of connected vertices:
0 1,
0 2,
1 3,
2 3,
2 4,
2 5,
3 5,
4 6,
5 6, and the expected output is: 0 2 4 6 5 3 1, but my code prints this: 0 2 5 6 4 3 1

Comment: First of all, both output are valid DFS run - it s depends in the order of the the edges store on `E[vertex]` - in your case (2,4) in before (2,5).
Notice 2 small changes: DFS, according to your pseudo code mark visited on vertices and you mark the edges. And pseudo mark and push and you push and mark

Comment: Thank you for clarifying it.